# @Published property testing

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I'm looking for some advice in writing unit tests. I've got a `@Published` property that holds view state inside my view model:

```
struct State: Equatable {
  var isLoading: Bool = true
  var names: [String] = []
}

@Published var state: State = .init()
```

The state variable changes over time, which is what I wanted to test. Here's an example of one such test:

```
func testViewLoaded() async throws {
  let vm = ViewModel(...)
  let expectedStates = [
    State(isLoading: true, names: []), // initial state
    State(isLoading: false, names: []),
    State(isLoading: false, names: [ ... ])
  ]
  let states = try await vm.$state.values.prefix(expectedStates.count).reduce(into: []) { $0.append($1) }
  XCTAssertEqual(expectedStates, states)
}
```

The issue I'm having is that this test will sometimes fail. It seems that the following line that creates a subscription will sometimes fail to pick up the initial state:

```
let states = try await vm.$state.values.prefix...
```

Is there something I can do to make my test more deterministic?

Comment: It might be that deterministic behaviour is a problem of the production code, not of the unit test.